# FFmpeg error when using --filter-complex with nvenc codec "Filter amerge has an unconnected output"

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have a video file with:

```
    Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:39:07.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25234 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 3440x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:18], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:39:07.250000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track1
      DURATION        : 00:39:07.157000000
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track2
      DURATION        : 00:39:07.157000000
```

I am trying to do 2 actions in one command:

1. Merge audio channels 0 and 1 together (both stereo)
2. Reencode the video with hevc

Run separately the two commands work:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i stuff.mkv -filter_complex "[0:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -ac 2 -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy other-stuff.mkv

ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -i other-stuff.mkv -c:a copy -map 0 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 6M -maxrate:v result.mkv
```

However my attempt at merging them results in the error:

```
ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -i stuff.mkv -filter_complex "[0:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -ac 2 -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 6M -maxrate:v result.mkv
"Filter amerge has an unconnected output"
```

My basic understanding of how mapping works tells me that this should be fine, but clearly I am missing something.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and report back:

```sh
ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -i stuff.mkv -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -ac 2 -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 6M -maxrate:v result.mkv
```

The `amerge` filter [requires two or more mapped inputs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge-1), as shown above.